# using nested loops - for loop

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have 2 questions regarding using nested loops.

1. I am iterating over soccer_match to create a new list with the colors of each team. So far, I have

```
colors = []

for color in soccer_match:
    colors.append(color['colors'])

colors
```

Which gives me [['blue', 'white', 'red'], ['green', 'gold']]. How would I be able to combine the two lists into one? I haven't learned list comprehension or functions yet.

2. How do I iterate over soccer_match to create a list with only the captains of each team? I'm assuming that I should use a nested for loop to look for 'captain' = True but not sure how to put that code.

Here is the given example. Thank you!

```
soccer_match = [
  { "home_team": True,
    "away_team": False,
    "country": "France",
    "num_passes": 484,
    "passes_completed": 423,
    "fouls_committed": 16,
    "colors": ["blue", "white", "red"],
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Hugo LLORIS",
        "captain": True,
        "shirt_number": 1,
        "position": "Goalie"
      },
      {
        "name": "Benjamin PAVARD",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 2,
        "position": "Defender"
      },
      {
        "name": "Raphael VARANE",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 4,
        "position": "Defender"
      },
      {
        "name": "Samuel UMTITI",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 5,
        "position": "Defender"
      },
      {
        "name": "Paul POGBA",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 6,
        "position": "Midfield"
      },
      {
        "name": "Antoine GRIEZMANN",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 7,
        "position": "Forward"
      },
      {
        "name": "Kylian MBAPPE",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 10,
        "position": "Forward"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ousmane DEMBELE",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 11,
        "position": "Forward"
      },
      {
        "name": "Corentin TOLISSO",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 12,
        "position": "Midfield"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ngolo KANTE",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 13,
        "position": "Midfield"
      },
      {
        "name": "Lucas HERNANDEZ",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 21,
        "position": "Defender"
      }
    ],
  },
  { "home_team": False,
    "away_team": True,
    "country": "Australia",
    "num_passes": 390,
    "passes_completed": 332,
    "fouls_committed": 19,
    "colors": ["green", "gold"],
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "Mathew RYAN",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 1,
        "position": "Goalie"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mark MILLIGAN",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 5,
        "position": "Defender"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mathew LECKIE",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 7,
        "position": "Forward"
      },
      {
        "name": "Robbie KRUSE",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 10,
        "position": "Forward"
      },
      {
        "name": "Andrew NABBOUT",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 11,
        "position": "Forward"
      },
      {
        "name": "Aaron MOOY",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 13,
        "position": "Midfield"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mile JEDINAK",
        "captain": True,
        "shirt_number": 15,
        "position": "Midfield"
      },
      {
        "name": "Aziz BEHICH",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 16,
        "position": "Defender"
      },
      {
        "name": "Joshua RISDON",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 19,
        "position": "Defender"
      },
      {
        "name": "Trent SAINSBURY",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 20,
        "position": "Defender"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tom ROGIC",
        "captain": False,
        "shirt_number": 23,
        "position": "Midfield"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and how to provide a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: so you would like the the output to be ["red","blue","white","green","gold"]

Comment: The fastest way to flatten the list I recently discovered is `flattened = sum(YOUR_LIST, [])`

Comment: That about duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name your variables according to what they represent. In this case, each element of `soccer_match` represents a *team*.

Now for each team, `team['colors']` is a list. For example, the first team has `team['colors'] = ["blue", "white", "red"]`. Since you want to add all elements of this list to your main `colors` list, use the `lst.extend(x)` method to add all elements to your current list `lst` from a given list `x`. `lst.append(x)` adds the entire list `x` as a single element to `lst`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

To find captains, loop over all players in each team. If that player's `'captain'` key is `True`, append the player to the `captains` list.

```
colors = []
captains = []

for team in soccer_match:
    colors.extend(team['colors'])
    for player in team['players']:
        if player['captain']:
            captains.append(player)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll keep future questions to 1 per. I have a secondary question. when the loop is iterating through the team['players'] does it automatically figure that it shouldn't append any players with 'captain' = False?

Comment: @imkusoh re. _" does it automatically figure that it shouldn't append any players with 'captain' = False"_: No! We asked it to do `captains.append(player)` only if `player['captain']` is `True`, because that's how `if` statements work: the code inside that block will be executed _only if_ the condition is true.

Answer (score 6):

Replace `colors.append` with `colors.extend`.